# How to change Picker Border color in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**My borderless custom renderer for picker**

```
public class BorderlessPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        public static void Init() { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                Control.Background = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

It will change the picker list text color as white. please see the screenshot [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code of [PickerRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs), you will find that the `Dialog` is totally generated in the code behind.

So here to set a `Transparent`(border-less) background, we can re-write the `Click` event of this control, for example:

```cs
public class BorderlessPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer
{
    private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
    private AlertDialog _dialog;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
            return;

        Control.Click += Control_Click;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Control.Click -= Control_Click;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker model = Element;

        var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
        if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
        {
            picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
            picker.MinValue = 0;
            picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
            picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
            picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
            picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
        }

        var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        layout.AddView(picker);

        ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);

        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        builder.SetView(layout);
        builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
        builder.SetNegativeButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel, (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
            // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
            Control?.ClearFocus();
            _dialog = null;
        });
        builder.SetPositiveButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Ok, (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
            // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
            if (Element != null)
            {
                if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                    Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
                // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
            }
            _dialog = null;
        });

        _dialog = builder.Create();
        _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
        {
            ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
        };
        _dialog.Show();
        _dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
    }
}
```

Rendering image of this custom picker:

[image]

The font color and button's style can be modified as you need since you created this dialog by yourself. And the style of the dialog also depends on the style of your app.